Read 16 bit color depth image with Wand
I want to process a 24-bit image in 16-bit mode with Wand. This is how I read the image
from wand.image import Image as WandImage

source_file='img/in.tif'

with WandImage(filename=source_file, depth=16) as img:
    print(img.depth)
    print(max(img.export_pixels()))

the output is 8 and 255, so the color depth is still 8 bit. The depth=16 argument did not change anything. What is going wrong? My wand version is
Wand 0.6.13
ImageMagick 7.1.1-38 Q16-HDRI x64 b0ab922:20240901 https://imagemagick.org


Your numbering is confusing.  A 24-bit image means RGB with 8 bits per component.  Are you talking about 16 bits per PIXEL or 16 bits per COMPONENT?  And if you mean 16 bits per pixel, do you mean RGB 5:6:5 or do you mean grayscale?  If the image is 24-bit RGB, you can't force it to be read as 16-bit.  You'll need to read it, and then convert it.

@TimRoberts You are right, I am solving a non existing problem. I misunderstood what 24-bit means. Thanks for your correction.
